# How can a file extension be captured using gawk's gensub?

Tags: awk

Let's say a `gawk` variable `fpath` contains a full file path with an extension, i.e. `tmp/myfile.txt`. However, this file extension could be any file extension. How would just the file extension be returned using `gensub`? There's a documentation page on `gensub` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).

Comment: `fpath` is a variable in awk or shell context?

Comment: @Inian It would be in the awk/gawk context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use `gensub` AT ANY PRICE then do it as follow:

```
awk 'BEGIN{fpath="tmp/myfile.txt";print gensub(/.*\./, "", 1, fpath)}' emptyfile.txt
```

output

```
txt
```

Beware that this solution will delete anything up to last `.` so for say `tmp/myfile.tar.gz` you will get `gz`

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: No need to beware; it won't delete anything, it just won't output _anything up to last `.`_.

Comment: What about if you tweak the regex to start at the beginning of the string, hit the last `/`, then stop at the first `.`? What would that look like?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have shell variable you could simply do it with setting appropriate field separators like as following. Simply set field separator to `.` and print the last field value here.

```
echo "tmp/myfile.txt" | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: I'm aware. This doesn't answer what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

A simple awk that removes everything until last dot:

```sh
awk '{sub(/^.*\./, "")} 1' <<< 'tmp/myfile.txt'
txt

awk '{sub(/^.*\./, "")} 1' <<< 'tmp/folder/myfile.csv'
csv
```

Or a similar `sed`:

```sh
sed 's/.*\.//' <<< /folder/myfile.csv
csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$fpath` is a shell variable whose value you want to pass to `awk`, I'd suggest to use shell features. For example, with `bash`:

```sh
$ f='tmp/myfile.txt'
$ echo "${f##*.}"
txt

$ f='tmp/myfile.txt.abc'
$ echo "${f##*.}"
abc
```

`##*.` will delete till last `.` in the string. Use `".${f##*.}"` if you need the `.` as well. See [Parameter Expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) for details.

Comment: I'm aware. This doesn't answer what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can hack the awk NF even further :

```
g/mawk -F. '$0=$NF'
```

Since i don't care about replacing `FS` with `OFS`, just directly overwrite the full row `$0` with just extension at `$NF`.

i've also written them outside of `{ }`, which means right after that assignment, the extension will directly be printed.

only minor downside that directories/folders will also be printed if they've been piped in, and files with no extension like the typical README will have full filename printed verbatim.

no need to call `sub()`, `gsub()`, `index()`, `match()`, `gensub()`, or even the `print` statement. heck, no regex needed.